# Enviar JTable a otra clase

Tags: java, jtable

necesito enviar los datos de un jtable que se encuentran en mi clase principal a un jdialog que de acuerdo a algunos seteos fabrica un pdf con esa tabla. Uso getters y setters que se encuentran en mi clase principal para enviar esos datos. Cuando quiero utilizar los datos del jTable de la clase principal, instancio la clase principal, pero como en su constructor jTable comienza null, me exporta una tabla nula a mi jdialog.
Espero se haya entendido, adjunto codigo recortado.

Clase principal:

```
public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private TableModel modelo;

/**
 * Creates new form Principal
 */
public Principal() {
    initComponents();
    setTitle("Laboratorio 3.0");
    Otras.colocarColumnas(jTable1);
}
private void generar_informeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    this.setTabla(jTable1);
    Opciones opciones = new Opciones(this, true);
    opciones.setVisible(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);

}                                               


public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Principal().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
public JTable getTabla(){
    return jTable1;
}

public void setTabla(JTable jTable1){
    this.jTable1 = jTable1;
}
```

Clase Opciones, es el jdialog que debe recuperar los datos del jtable que se encuentra en la clase Principal

```
public class Opciones extends javax.swing.JDialog {

/**
 * Creates new form Opciones
 */
Datos_Informe dt;
JTextField campo;
String obser;
JTable tabla;

public Opciones(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    rellenarComboBox();
    java.util.Date hoy = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    txt_emision.setText(formateador.format(hoy));

}
private void btnAceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (null != date_anal.getDate() && null != date_muest.getDate()
            && null != date_recep.getDate()) {

        try {
            Informe informe = new Informe();

            dt = new Datos_Informe();
            this.guardarDatosInforme(dt);
            informe.guardarInforme();

            //System.out.println(dt.getSolicitante());
            principal = new Principal();

            informe.cargarDatosPdf(dt,principal.getTabla());
            this.dispose();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Opciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Completar todos los campos fecha",
                "Atención", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }


}
```

Informe, es una clase que transforma esa tabla que recibe por parametro en un pdf.
Soy bastante nuevo, pero esto me tiene bloqueado.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tú hacer una nueva instancia`principal = new Principal();`
El problemas es que al hacer eso, se creará una nueva instancia donde el valor que tú quieres no se ha definido aún...
Remplaza lo siguiente:

```
public Opciones(Prinsipal parent, boolean modal) { super(parent, modal);
    prinsipal = parent;
    initComponents();
    rellenarComboBox();
    java.util.Date hoy = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    txt_emision.setText(formateador.format(hoy));
```

}

Después quita la parte de código que te he mencionado.

Comment: Gracias Christian! eso era lo que me faltaba! Abrazo!